# Is there any way to debug a JSP Custom tag in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tags, jstl

I am making some experiments with JSP, JSTL and the [custom tags](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19502-01/819-3669/bnalj/index.html)

Is there any way to debug a Custom Tag **doTag()** method in Eclipse, using the Debug perspective, breakpoints, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is regular Java code. Set your breakpoint in the Tag's Java source, start your Tomcat in debug mode, open your JSP and you're in.

Comment: I did not know you can Tomcat could be launched in Debug Mode, thanks!

Comment: If you register Tomcat in Eclipse and start from there, you are free to go.